# C, multidimensional unequal array

Tags: c

I'm trying to declare something like this in plane C

```
const unsigned char test[][][][] = {{0x22,0x33},{0x22,0x33,0x44},{0x22,0x33,0x44,0x55},{0x22,0x33,0x45}};
```

but is not valid. I seek for a elegant way to store 4 arrays that can be addressed by index, but they are unequal sized since contains some RS232 command to a device.

I'm looking for command[INITIALISE], command[RESET] and so on.

Thanks very much in advance for suggestions.

Comment: Pick the largest extents and leave the unneeded elements unset?

Comment: Just store them as string array : `const unsigned char* test[] = {"AB", "ABC", "ABCD", ...}`. I mean that you can terminate every data portion by zero (or other symbol that can't be in data).

Comment: Thanks very much all for valuable comments,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
const unsigned char test[][4] = {{0x22,0x33},{0x22,0x33,0x44},{0x22,0x33,0x44,0x55},{0x22,0x33,0x45}};
```

Comment: Where 4 is not the number of elements in this array but the maximum number of elements in the subarrays.  However, I want to see how you'll know how many elements each one really contains...

Comment: It's not possible afaik. You should get a compiler warning if the array is too small.

Comment: And you'd either need separate counters, or a sentinel value in each array to know where it ends.

Comment: @nickie: If the data can never contain zero bytes, then you could terminate each initializer with 0x00 to indicate the end.  Using strings, you could write `const unsigned char *test[] = { "\x22\x33", "\x22\x33\x44", "\x22\x33\x44\x55", "\x22\x33\x45" };` to get the null-terminated strings - at a cost of a pointer per entry.  If the commands are all shorter than about 8 bytes, you'd do better with the 2D array (`unsigned char test[][8]`) and a set of initializers like those I gave — or the braced equivalents.

Comment: @nickie: That's true. I did not think about the underlying problem at all -- just saw the code.

Comment: Make the first value of the array its size.  Similar to Pascal strings.  Assuming you are dealing with arrays that contain 256 values or less (yes, not 255 because you can assume no arrays contain zero values).

Comment: Thanks @undur_gongor, I gave the answer because this is what I've asked for :) However, #Kyle Lemons excellent noticed that I need 0x00 terminator at each command or i think I can reserve one last byte as command length. Thank both very much,

Answer (score 6):

You can't do this in a single variable declaration, in general.  What I would suggest would be something like this:

```
const unsigned char command1[] = {0x2, 0x3, 0x0};
const unsigned char command2[] = {0x3, 0x0};
const unsigned char *commands[] = {command1, command2};
```

Note that each of the commands has a `0x0`-terminator; this is required because otherwise there will be no way to know how many bytes are in the command string.

If you happen to know the maximum length of a command, then you can do the following:

```
const unsigned char commands[][MAX_LENGTH+1] = {
   {0x2, 0x3},
   {0x3},
};
```

which will similarly allow you to know the length of the command by looking for a `0x0`.  Note that this will waste space, because there are extra zero-bytes for each command that is not at the maximum length.

This answer assumes that `0x0` is not a valid command byte.  If it is, you'll need to store the lengths of each command separately.